# PayPal: Choosing multiple items with quantities

Tags: html, forms, paypal

I have made a PayPal form where I wish to sell multiple items and quantities (see screenshot). However when I use the code similar to the one written below I get a error if some of the items haven't been selected (quantity=0). The error says "A quantity value must be an integer greater than or equal to one." But I can't figure out how I could make the form behave like I want if I can't have some items with the quantity of 0.

Does anyone have a solution that fits my needs? I wouldn't like to have a "add to cart" button on every item.

Thanks!

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemail">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="First item">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="9">
<select name="quantity_1"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select>

<!-- more items -->

<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

[screenshot http://kejk.se/skar.png](http://kejk.se/skar.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to code in the logic not to send over items that have no quantities.  The cart upload would only want to send over an item that has a quantity of atleast 1.

Comment: So, some fancy javascript is needed then? To check if the selected value is 0 and then remove the <input name="item_name_x">

Comment: Corect, some type of script/logic would need to be used to do this before passing it over.  Otherwise you would need to be using an add to cart button instead of the cart upload method.  Then the buyer would need to add each item to the cart before checking out.

Comment: Ok, thanks, are sweating over some js-code right now but it should resolve at last.