# PayPal jscript: Single form: send multiple items with dropdown quantities = 0?

Tags: html, forms, paypal

From reading another question, [PayPal: Choosing multiple items with quantities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931241/paypal-choosing-multiple-items-with-quantities); I understand I need some fancy javascript To check if the selected value is 0 and if so remove the item before passing it on to paypal. Not knowing jscript, can anyone help me do so with the form below? It's for a very worth cause :-)

```
<!--Paypal Buy Now Code:-->

<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx.xxx@yyy.zzz">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

<!--First Item-->
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Adult - Barn Dance & BBQ">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="ADBDBBQ">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="15.00">
Adult - Barn Dance & BBQ
<select name="undefined_quantity_1" value="">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</p>

<!--Second Item-->
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Child - Barn Dance & BBQ">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" value="CHBDBBQ">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="5.00">
Child - Barn Dance & BBQ
<select name="undefined_quantity_2" value="">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</p>

<!--Third Item--> 
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="5 Raffle Tickets">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_3" value="ARAFTIX">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="3.00">
Additional 5 Raffle Tickets
<select name="undefined_quantity_3" value="">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</p>

<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.yyy.zzz/thankyou.htm">

<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif"
border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" 
width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!!
Lars

Answer (score 0):

The `undefined_quantity` variable is only available to Buy Now buttons - not cart buttons.

It's used to determine whether or not an item has a changeable quantity. Where the buyer can pick the amount of items they want to purchase on the checkout page.

The variable I believe you're looking for is `quantity_x`. The value would determine the number of items the buyer is purchasing.

Comment: I tried that variable too. Regrettably, I get the same error msg. that the value must be 1 or greater. It doesn't like a null or zero value for any of the entries.

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned that. The values for the item quantity and amount require a positive value.